# $M$ and $S$ have the same characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, matrix-decomposition

I have read a linear algebra theorem called **Jordan–Chevalley decomposition**, which says that:

If $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ then there exists $S,N\in M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that  $M=S+N$, where $S$ is diagonalizable, $N$ is nilpotent, and  $SN=NS$.

But I don't understand why $M$ and $S$ have the same characteristic polynomial?

an idea plaese?

Comment: Have you read the proof of this theorem ? It gives an explicit construction of $S$ and $N$, and you can see that $S$ is exactly constructed to have the same eigenvalues with multiplicities as $M$.

Comment: @Made One way to show this is to note that because $NS = SN$, $S$ and $N$ must be simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think you meant simultaneously triangularisable, as you said in the duplicate I linked in.   (Note to others: invertibility is in the title of the linked post but is irrelevant to the result.)

Comment: @user8675309 Right, of course. Good find